# jQuery resize video, reset the size

Tags: javascript, css, video, resize, reset

I have 3 videos. What I want to do, is:
Click on video1 > video2 and video3 gets smaller by 50% > click on video2 > video1 and video3 resets to their original size > video1 and video3 gets smaller by 50%.

At the moment I am at this point:
I make 2 videos re-size after I click on video1.
After I click on the same video, video2 and video3 re-size to their original size.
But if I click on video2 (WHEN IT IS SMALLER by 50%), then video1 gets smaller than original (by 50%), video3 goes back to original size.

[Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/utCb6/11/) (for some reason it does not work on my PC there).

HTML code:

```
<div>
    <video id="video1" class="normal" height="200" width="300">
    <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
     HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
</div>

<div>
    <video id="video2" class="normal" height="200" width="300">
    <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
     HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
</div>


<div>
    <video id="Video3" class="small" height="200" width="300">
    <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
     HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.normal {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1, 1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1, 1);
        transform: scale(1, 1);
}

.big {
   -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
   -moz-transform: scale(2, 2);
    -ms-transform: scale(2, 2);
        transform: scale(2, 2);

}

.small {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
    transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
}

#video1{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
#video2{
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in;
   -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s ease-in;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
#video3{
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}
```

JavaScript code:

```
$("#video1").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('big');
    $("#video2").toggleClass('small');
    $("#video3").toggleClass('small');
});

$("#video2").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('big');
    $("#video1").toggleClass('small');
    $("#video3").toggleClass('small');
});

$("#video3").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('big');
    $("#video1").toggleClass('small');
    $("#video2").toggleClass('small');

});
```

How can I reset the video size before re-sizing it?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Before you toggle the small class you need to check whether the element already has it. If it does, your function should not apply the class again.

Comment: Could you help me out HOW to check whether the element already has the class? @Paulie_D ? I'm very new to JavaScript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toggle class is a nice feature but i don't think that is the best option for you to use here.
think you could use a single function and call it with all, something close to

```
function videoClicked(e)
{
    //get a referance to the video clicked
    var sender = e.target;

    //get all the videos 
    var $videos = $('.videos');
    //if the sender had class big it was already clicked and we need to reset all to normal
    if($(sender).hasClass('big'))
    {
        //remove all big classes
        $videos.removeClass('big');
        //and small class
        $videos.removeClass('small');
        //then add normal class
        $videos.addClass('normal');
        //we are done, lets go home
        return;
    }

    //remove big from all videos
    $videos.removeClass('big');
    //add small to videos that were not the sender (aka clicked video)
    $videos.not(sender).addClass('small');
    //add big to the sender
    $(sender).addClass('big');
}
```

I would add a class .video to all and then add

```
//this is jquery short hand for an on load function
$(function()
{
    //add event for all videos 
    $('.video').click(videoClicked);
});
```

Comment: Somehow this did not work for me, unfortunately. I suppose I am missing something or I'm just doing it all wrong, as I am very new with JavaScript.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom, can you add a jsbin for me to look at. did you add the class "video" to all three? are there any js errors being thrown?

Comment: finally, I made it working now. My fault - did not understand about classes.
But I still have one problem. I want that if I click on the same video again (which is already big), all 3 videos would go back to their original state. I've tried playing with your given code, but no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom the edit i just made should do it for you, did not run this so may not be 100% but should be close enough that you can work with it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. Honest respect from me, @workabyte !

Comment: Hi, @workabyte . I really like your solution of my query. But I have another problem right now.
When I click on video, I want that not-sender videos will move to other containers (actually, each video to separate div). I made it so far, but I cannot get the videos back from changed div to original ones, when I click on the video again. Any idea?

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom, can you post another question with some code and i will take a look, better if you can put it in a jsbin and post a link to it so i can tinker. Can definitely help.

Comment: Yes, here it is, I hope there is enough information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740985/javascript-move-multiple-elements-to-separate-divs-and-back