# Javascript move multiple elements to separate div's and back

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, move, back

There are 3 videos, placed in 3 separate div's.
There also are 3 separate div's, but in other position of a page (lets say contA and contB and contC).
I want that if I click on the video1, then video2 and video3 goes to contA and contB, and video1 goes to contC.
If I click video1 again, all videos go back to their original position.
If I click on video2 (while its in contA), then video1 goes to contA, video3 goes to contB, video2 goes to contC.

I have prepared a jsbin demo:
[Jsbin DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qiqafoma/7/edit)

Anyone could help? Appreciated!

EDIT: (Added a code as requested)

HTML:

```
    <div id="vid1">
          <video id="Video1" class="videos">
          <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
         HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
    </div>

    <div id="vid2">
          <video id="Video2" class="videos">
          <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
         HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
    </div>

    <div id="vid3">
          <video id="Video3" class="videos">
          <source src="http://www.craftymind.com/factory/html5video/BigBuckBunny_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>  
         HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
    </video>
    </div>

<div id="contA"><br>first container<br></div>
<div id="contB"><br>second container<br></div>
<div id="contC"><br>third container<br></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
    //add event for all videos 
    $('.videos').click(videoClicked);


function videoClicked(e)
{
        //get a referance to the video clicked
    var sender = e.target;

    //get all the videos 
    var $videos = $('.videos');

      $videos.appendTo('#contA');
      $videos.appendTo('#contB'); //but I need each video to be put to different div: #contA, #contB...

$videos.not(sender).appendTo('#contC'); //if I put the clicked video into this container, it does not go back to original one.
}
});
```

Comment: Posted as requested @j08691

Comment: The reason it doesn't work on the jsbin sample, is because no reference is added to JQuery. Easiest way to do that is to click the 'add library' button. That said, do you have a sample that also contains the divs contA, contB and contC? or are the current divs those containers?

Comment: @Me.Name I have edited the code, please check now

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a bit easier to test :) Just to be clear, when you say back to their original position, you mean the divs they started in at page layout right?

Comment: Yes, exactly: Video1 > vid1, Video2 > vid2, Video3 > vid3.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom can i trouble you to break up each movement a little more, not 100% clear.

Comment: @workabyte What I want to do, is:
1. If I click on video1, then video2 and video3 goes from div "vid2" and "vid3" to div "contA" and "contB" respectively. Video1 will go to "contC" then.
2. If I click on video2 (which is now in "contA"), then video1 (from contC) will go to "contA" and video3 (from contB) will go to "contB". Video2 will go to "contC".
3. If I click on the video, which is already in "contC", then all videos will go back to their original places: video1 to vid1, video2 to vid2 and video3 to vid3.

Comment: @StartedFromTheBottom OK, think i have a solution for you, or get you in the right direction. will post soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this is what you're looking for, but it's based on the naming convention used in the example. I also took the liberty of renaming contA/contB and contC to cont1, cont2 and cont3, because it's easier to manipulate.

[JSBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qiqafoma/14/edit)

```
  //remember last video clicked (you could check last container instead)
var lastclicked;

function videoClicked(e)
{
    //get a reference to the video clicked
    var sender = e.target;
  //get all the videos 
    var $videos = $('.videos');  

    if(sender==lastclicked){
      //reset to original positions

      $.each($videos,function(){
        var ind =     this.id.substring(this.id.length-1); //based on the video + number naming convention
        $(this).appendTo('#vid' + ind);
      });
      lastclicked = null;
      return;
    }

    lastclicked= sender;  

     var i = 1;  
     //place all non clicked videos in cont1/cont2/etc
     $.each($videos.not(sender),function()
     { 
       $(this).appendTo('#cont' + i++ );
     });

     //place the clicked video in the last container
     $(sender).appendTo('#cont' + i ); //always cont3 with fixed divs, but this is dynamic in case you add more


}
});
```

Comment: Works nicely, but I could not make it to back to their original positions. Might be my mistake somewhere, but I've used the same code for myself.

Comment: It works, only I got some other script there and they disturb each other. Will try to figure this out myself. Thanks a lot, my question is answered, @Me.Name !

Comment: Hey there, @Me.Name ! I have another problem related with video moving  between divs. Could you check [it out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509040/javascript-move-image-together-with-video-to-other-divs) ? Maybe you could help me with that as well. Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I will edit this answer as the desired results become more clear but i think i can give you some info to get you going in the right direction.

the section of code "but i need each video to be put to a diff cont"

I would leverage a data attribute and let each control keep track of itself.

```
    $video.each(function()
    { 
        var targetdiv = $(this).data('origonal-div');
        $(targetdiv.ToString()).append(this);
                    //optionally update the data value to keep track of the next location to append to.
    }
```

if you need more info post some questions with an update on the jsbin so i can see where you are having trouble.

Cheers

Comment: Hey there, @workabyte ! I have another problem related with video moving  between divs. Could you check [it out here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509040/javascript-move-image-together-with-video-to-other-divs) ? Maybe you could help me with that as well. Appreciated!